# Block Direct URL action that inserts into DB

Tags: php

I have an action in file viewreport it is about ticket:

```
if(isset($_GET['closeticket']) == 'true')

{

$db->query("update tickets set status='Closed' where id='$id'");

header("Location: viewreport?id=".$id."");
```

But even an user can close a ticket that doesn't belong to him via url.
So i want to block direct url action.

Here is the action

```
a href "viewreport?closeticket=true&id= <?php echo $id;?>" class="btn btn-danger" id="">Close</a>
```

Comment: Feel free to read about SQL injection, here's a related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: `if(isset($_GET['closeticket']) == 'true')` should be `if(isset($_GET['closeticket']))`.

Comment: 1. Prevent SQL injection. 2. Use POST instead. 3. Depend on an AUTH token, or server side verification (probably using php's `$_SESSION`).

Answer (score 0):

You should check if this operation belongs to the user via sessions or cookies.

it must be something like this

```
if($_SESSION["group"] == "Admin" ){
 // update operation.
}
```

I hope this would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the user is allowed closing that report, before executing.

Thus something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['closeticket'])) 
{
    $userIsAllowed = true; // your magic here
    if ($userIsAllowed) {
        $db->query("update tickets set status='Closed' where id=" . $db->quote($id));
        header("Location: viewreport?id=".$id."");
    } else {
        echo "You're not allowed closing this ticket";
    }
}
```

Make sure to properly escape your queries as mentioned in the comments (by chelmertz)

Comment: Is there any other method to block it via htaccess? Because it isn't working

Comment: Did you change `$userIsAllowed = true; // your magic here` with real code to determine if the current user is admin or somehow other allowed to close that ticket?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help , i don't want only admin to close that because if i would that is easy , but i want users to close their own tickets if they want. But they can close each-others ticket by url.Thats my problem

Comment: Well, then write the following in PHP. 1. Get the id/name of the currently loged in user, 2. Get the id/name of the owner of that ticket. 3. `$userIsAllowed = $isAdmin || $resultOf1 == $resultOf2;`

Comment: Thank you very much , I fixed it.